# É possível inserir dados de um Array em JS dentro de uma tabela pronta em HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

Boa noite galera, mais uma vez aqui me surgiu uma **dúvida.**

Tenho uma tabela pronta (e vazia) na página *HTML*, e eu gostaria de preencher ela usando *JS*, é possível? Vou deixar o código abaixo para melhor entendimento:

**HTML**

```
<table class="table table-bordered" id="tableClient">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">Nome</th>
        <th scope="col">Email</th>
        <th scope="col">CPF</th>
        <th scope="col">Criado em</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      
        <tr>
        <td id="name"></td>
        <td id="email"></td>
        <td id="cpf"></td>
        <td id="created"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Eu gostaria de preencher cada coluna, **name, email, cpf, created** usando arrays criados, mas infelizmente não consegui achar nada parecido que me desse uma luz..

Fico grato por quem puder me ajudar!

Comment: Sim é possível.

Comment: Opa, e ai Augusto, beleza? Você poderia me dar um exemplo de como fazer isso? Não quero ser folgado, mas eu não consegui encontrar nada parecido que pudesse me ajudar..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 - Você usa o document.createElement() para criar o **tr** e os **td**.

2 - Utiliza o .textContent para definir o conteúdo dos **tds**.

3 - Usa o .appendChild() para colocar os **tds** dentro do **tr** e colocar o **td** dentro do **tbody**.

```
var nome = 'Fulano';
var email= 'coisodostreco@gmailcom';
var cpf= '555.555.555-55';
var data= '01/01/2020';


var corpoTabela = document.querySelector('tbody');

var tr= document.createElement('tr');
var tdNome= document.createElement('td');
var tdEmail= document.createElement('td');
var tdCPF= document.createElement('td');
var tdData= document.createElement('td');

tdNome.textContent = nome;
tdEmail.textContent = email;
tdCPF.textContent = cpf;
tdData.textContent = data;

tr.appendChild(tdNome);
tr.appendChild(tdEmail);
tr.appendChild(tdCPF);
tr.appendChild(tdData);
corpoTabela.appendChild(tr);
```